# Django query of table with implicit join on itself

Tags: django

I've read the documentation and looked at other questions posted here, but I can't find or figure out whether this is possible in Django.

I have a model relating actors and movies:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    title_id = models.CharField('Title ID', max_length=20, db_index=True)
    name_id = models.CharField('Name ID', max_length=20, db_index=True)
    role = models.CharField('Role', max_length=300, default='?')
```

This is a single table that has pairs of actors and movies, so given a movie (title_id), there's a row for each actor in that movie. Similarly, given an actor (name_id), there's a row for every movie that actor was in.

I need to execute a query to return the list of all title_id's that are related to a given title_id by a common actor. The SQL for this query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r2.title_id 
    FROM role as r1, role as r2 
    WHERE r1.name_id = r2.name_id 
        AND r1.title_id != r2.title_id 
        AND r1.title_id = <given title_id>
```

Can something like this be expressed in a single Django ORM query, or am I forced to use two queries with some intervening code? (Or raw SQL?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would break this into Actor and Movie table to make it easier to query, but your requirement is there so I will give it a go

```
def get_related_titles(title_id)
    all_actors = Role.objects.filter(title_id=title_id).values_list('pk', flat=True)
    return Role.objects.filter(pk__in=all_actors).exclude(title_id=title_id) # maybe u need .distinct() here
```

this should give you one query, validate it this way:

```
print(get_related_titles(some_title_id).query)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @rabbit.aaron. That's kind of where I was--one function, but actually two queries. (I think the first query has to fully execute and return its results in order for the second to construct?)

Comment: No, because querysets are lazily excuted, thus it wont be evaluated until you loop through it. In this case it should generate a sub query. But all should be in one query.

Comment: I know about lazy execution, but are you sure that applies in this case? The second query is not an extension of the first (you're not doing "all_actors.filter ..."), and I think the full data set from the all_actors QuerySet is needed in order to compile the __in lookup of the returned QuerySet (which /would/ be lazily executed.)

Comment: You can test it with the plugin I wrote. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-print-sql

Comment: Nice! (and nice tool, too). It turns the first query into an embedded select, so your solution is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the direction!